# Why is the Toast not working? Is there anything wrong in this code?

Tags: java, android

I have just started with Android Development, i am facing an error with toast. I searched on Google as well, but couldn't fix my problem.

> Here is the java Code:

```
package com.example.uibasicssection2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnHello:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnHello = findViewById(R.id.btnHello);
        btnHello.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
}
```

> XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Say Hello"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnHello"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i run the above code I can see the button but when i click on the button there is no Toast Notification, is there anything wrong with this code?

Comment: Wondering why you have placed the switch block inside the  onClick method. I would suggest you to 
1. Set a breakpoint at that code and run the App in debug mode. and step over to understand how the code is executing.
2. Write a Log statement in the onClick method, to check if the execution flow is reaching the code block you're written.

Answer (score 0):

//pass activity context

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();